# ¿Como colorear lineas según un dato en un listado en Angular 7?

Tags: angular

Pues he buscado pero no me queda nada claro. esto es tal como lo tengo para ilustraros del problema

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dato of datos; let i = index" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dato.versionapi = Inaccesible : 'red'}">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center" style="padding-bottom: 5%; border: 100px; background-color:#243a51; color:#ffffff">
        <div class="col col col-lg-3">
            {{ dato.nombre }}
        </div>
        <div class="col col col-lg-3">
            {{ dato.ws }}
        </div>
        <div class="col col col-lg-3  row justify-content-center">
            {{ dato.versionapi }}
        </div>
        <div class="col col col-lg-3  row justify-content-center">
            {{ dato.ws_provider }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="color: #000000;" />
</ng-container>
```

La idea es que la fila en la que el dato.versionapi sea igual a Inaccesible toda la fila se ponga en rojo.

Comment: No me queda muy claro, la variable Inaccesible que es? Si me lo explicas intentare ayudarte.

Comment: El elemento `ng-container` no puede tener estilos, ya que _Angular_ no lo pone en el **DOM**.

Comment: {{dato.versionapi}} es la variable y dentro pueden llevar numeros de la version o contener un texto que diga que es Inaccesible

Comment: Entonces `Inaccesible` es un string o una variable?

Comment: es un string, en Typescript esta declarado como "any"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te he comentado antes, el `ng-container` no puede tener estilos, ya que **Angular** no lo pone en el **DOM**, y el `ngStyle` lo tendrás que colocarlo, por ejemplo, en un `div`. El `ngStyle` se utiliza mas para poner estilos mediante variables y condiciones sobre los estilos, el `ngClass` para poner una clase css si se cumple la condición. También se puede poner condiciones al `ngStyle` con un estilo en concreto.

- Opción **ngStyle**:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="dato.versionapi == Inaccesible && {'background-color': 'red'}">
  <!-- Tu bloque -->
</div>
```

- Opción **ngClass**:

Archivo `.html`:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'nombre-de-la-clase': dato.versionapi == Inaccesible}">
  <!-- Tu bloque -->
</div>
```

Archivo `.css`:

```css
nombre-de-la-clase {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Saludos